# How to get the Session ID from a Zend_Auth session?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-session

Using the default [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.html) session storage (PHP Sessions), it creates a session ID and puts it in a cookie. If I want to get at the authenticated user's username (identity), the `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()` method gets that. However, I want to get at the user's session ID. I can get at it just by looking at `$_COOKIE`, or using `session_id()` but that seems hackish, and if I ever moved away from PHP Session storage might it break? So what's the best way to get the current session ID of the Zend_Auth session?

Comment: What about using a standard function for its intended purpose is hackish?

Comment: @tuespetre if I were creating sessions with `session_start()`, then getting the ID with `session_id()` does make sense and is not hackish. But, since I'm working with a library that may be doing other things, or may be doing other things in the future, it seems a disconnect to use a higher-level library function along with a low-level core call.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you're going to find a nice way to do this. If such a method existed it would be defined in `Zend_Auth_Storage_Interface`, but non-session types of storage don't necessarily have a session ID equivalent so the auth storage classes don't have any abstraction for this. The closest you'll get is probably:

```
Zend_Session::getId()
```

but this just calls PHP's `session_id()`, since `Zend_Session` is dependent on the in-built PHP session functionality.